# How to use excel to pdf REST api provided by ConvertApi?

Tags: java, convertapi

I am planning to use, excel to pdf api (REST) in my java code provided by ConvertApi.
please share the code snippet to be used for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the code below

Library

```
package com.excel2pdfconvert.example;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class Xls2PDFConvertBean {

    private File file;
    private String outputDir;
    
    
    private String filesize;
    private String filename;
    
    
    
    public void setOutputDir(String outputDir) {
        this.outputDir = outputDir;
    }
    public void setExcelFile(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    
    public String getFilesize() {
        return filesize;
    }
    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Run request for page conversion
     * @return resultcode "0" in error, "1" in success
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
     */
    public String doRequest() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        
        String resultcode = "0"; 
        
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/xlsx/to/pdf");
        
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );
        
        // For File parameters
        entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(file, "binary/octet-stream"));
        
        httppost.setEntity( entity );
        
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Header rcHeader = response.getFirstHeader("result");
            if(rcHeader != null){
                
                resultcode = rcHeader.getValue();
                
                if("True".equals(resultcode)){
                    
                    filesize = response.getFirstHeader("filesize").getValue();
                    filename = response.getFirstHeader("OutputFileName").getValue();
                    
                    HttpEntity hentity = response.getEntity();
                    if(hentity != null){

                        InputStream istream = hentity.getContent();
                        File file = new File(outputDir+File.separator+filename);
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        
                        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                        int num = 0;
                        while( (num = istream.read(b, 0, b.length)) > 0)
                            ostream.write(b, 0, num);
                        istream.close();
                        ostream.flush();
                        ostream.close();
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
        return resultcode;
    }
    
}
```

The web page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="com.excel2pdfconvert.example.Xls2PDFConvertBean" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.File" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Excel2Pdf Api Demo
</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function BeforeConvert() {
            document.getElementById('LabelMessage').innerHTML = 'Please wait...';
            document.getElementById('HyperLinkFile').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('LabelFileSize').innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById('LabelFileName').innerHTML = '';
        }
    </script> 
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div>
        <h1>Excel2Pdf Api Demo</h1>
        Upload Excel file:&nbsp;
        <input type="file" name="excel" />&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="btnConvert" value="Convert" onclick="BeforeConvert();" id="btnConvert" />
        <br />
        <br />
        
        
<% if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
    
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    
    File uploadedFile = null;
    String[] allowedExt = {"csv", "xls", "xlsx", "xlsb", "xlt", "xltx"};
    
    // Process the uploaded items
    Iterator iter = items.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

        if (! item.isFormField()) {
             
            //Check for valid excel extensions
            String fileName = item.getName();
            boolean isValid = false;
             for(String ext : allowedExt){
                 if(fileName.contains(ext)){
                    isValid = true;
                    break;
                 }
             }
             
             if(isValid){
                 uploadedFile = new File(application.getRealPath("/") + "/" + fileName);
                 item.write(uploadedFile);
             }
        }
    }

    if(uploadedFile == null){
        out.println("<div>Please upload file in following format: csv, xls, xlsx, xlsb, xlt, xltx");
    }else{
        
        Xls2PDFConvertBean xls2pdf = new Xls2PDFConvertBean();
        xls2pdf.setOutputDir(application.getRealPath("/"));
        xls2pdf.setExcelFile(uploadedFile);
        String resultcode = xls2pdf.doRequest();
        
        //Remove uploaded file after conversion
        uploadedFile.delete();
        
        if(resultcode == null || "False".equals(resultcode)){
            out.println("<div>Can not convert file</div>");
        }else{
%>
        <span id="LabelMessage">Conversion successful  </span>
        <br />
        <a id="HyperLinkFile" href="<%= xls2pdf.getFilename() %>" >Click here to open file  </a>

        <br />
        <span id="LabelFileSize">File size: <%= xls2pdf.getFilesize() %></span>
        <br />
        <span id="LabelFileName">File name: <%= xls2pdf.getFilename() %></span>
 <%
            }
        }
    }else{
%>
    <span id="LabelMessage"></span>
<%      
    }
%>


    </div>
</form>
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This page http://do.convertapi.com/Excel2Pdf seems dead.

Comment: @JuanPabloMorales This is the [Excel to PDF API web page](https://www.convertapi.com/xlsx-to-pdf) and Rest API endpoint `https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/xlsx/to/pdf`